# So I'm trying to learn Dart/Flutter for the first time for my own project

Tags: double, average

new to Stack OF. I'm stuck on averages on Dartpad,it's not running the double average & I don't know why. I was watching YouTube tutorials, and it was working fine before with the average.

However, it's not calculating the double average when I run it on Dartpad now. Here is a screenshot. Not sure if I should start another pad with new lines of code. Any advice will be helpful & appreciated

Trying to calculate double average on Dartpad, I deleted the code and even started a new pad on the  Console, and it still wouldn't calculate the average, the problem persisted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.